# Inputting variable data in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to make a shiny app where users upload a text file and can input the terms they want filter (so sentences that have two particular words or phrases). then they can download the results. My script so far looks like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Download data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose .txt file",
                multiple = F,
                accept = c(".txt")),
      textInput('energy_co', 'Name of energy company'),
      textInput('asset', 'name of Asset Manager'),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
    
  )
)




server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

  
  output$table <- renderTable({  
  req(input$file1)
  
    data <- read_lines(input$file1$datapath)
    text_df <- as_data_frame(data)
    
    company_data <- text_df %>% 
      filter(str_detect(terms, input$asset)) %>%   
      filter(str_detect(terms, input$energy_co)) %>% 
      distinct(.)
    
    company_data
    
    })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(company_data, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(company_data, file1, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can upload the dataset (a .txt file) but nothing happens either when I try and render the table or when I try and download the results as a csv. I think the server script might need to be reactive? any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Download data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose .txt file",
                multiple = F,
                accept = c(".txt")),
      textInput('energy_co', 'Name of energy company'),
      textInput('asset', 'name of Asset Manager'),
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
    
  )
)


options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  company_data <- reactive({
    req(input$file1,input$asset,input$energy_co)
    
    data <- read_lines(input$file1$datapath)
    text_df <- as_data_frame(data)
    
    company_data <- text_df %>% 
      filter(str_detect(terms, input$asset)) %>%   
      filter(str_detect(terms, input$energy_co)) %>% 
      distinct(.)
    company_data
  })
  
  
  output$table <- renderTable({  
    
    company_data()
    
  })
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(company_data, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(company_data(), file1, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Gets the error message `Warning: Error in stri_detect_regex: argument str should be a character vector (or an object coercible to)` when I try and input the asset or energy_co data

Comment: Your usage of str_detect is the issue here.  Proper usage: `fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pinapple")`
`str_detect(fruit, "a")`  Is `terms` a vector?

Comment: Ah so I've managed to resolve that issue. But now it throws Warning: Error in gsub: input string 4 is invalid UTF-8

Comment: It depends on your txt file.  I don't get that error.

Comment: Hmm, looks like shiny has trouble parsing non UTF-8 characters then.